# Loading data with AsyncStorage in new Tab Screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

How should I be using Async Storage to display data in a new navigation screen?

I tried to set a state for the items in the storage:

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('sightings');
      if (value !== null) {
        console.log(value);
        this.setState({ sightings: JSON.parse(value) });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

But I am not sure where to set this? ComponentWillMount will load once? But what if I navigate back to another screen then come back again to this one where the data must load?

OR I thought to not use state but use _retrieveData as a variable in the template?

```
render() {    
    return (<Container>
        <Content>
          <List>
          {_retrieveData.map(sighting => {
              <ListItem>
                <Left>
                  <Text>{sighting.species}</Text>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Text>{sighting.timestamp}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                  <Badge success>
                    <Text>{sighting.counter}</Text>
                  </Badge>
                </Right>
              </ListItem>
            })}
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

This is my navigation:

```
export default (MainScreenNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Start: { screen: AddSighting },
    Sightings: { screen: Sightings }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button vertical onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Start")}>
              <Icon name="apps" />
              <Text>Add sightings</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              badge
              vertical
              onPress={() =>
                props.navigation.navigate("Sightings", {
                  onNavigate: this.handleOnNavigate
                })
              }
            >
              <Badge>
                <Text>2</Text>
              </Badge>
              <Text>Sightings</Text>
              <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
));
```

Im not sure how this is supposed to be done the react way?

Answer (score 0):

`react-navigation` supports [adding listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to the screen. With this way you can update your data, in your case re-reading values from `AsyncStorage`

> **addListener** - *Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle*
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to them:
>
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

*Example from docs*

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);

// Remove the listener when you are done
didBlurSubscription.remove();

// Payload

{
  action: { type: 'Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION', key: 'StackRouterRoot' },
  context: 'id-1518521010538-2:Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION_Root',
  lastState: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  type: 'didBlur',
};
```